# sonarqube failed to start in centos 6

Tags: java, linux, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

```
[root@code-manage sonarqube-5.6]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

---

```
[root@code-manage sonarqube-5.6]# ./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh console
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2016.07.25 10:25:54 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /etc/sonarqube-5.6/temp
jvm 1    | 2016.07.25 10:25:54 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.el6_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/etc/sonarqube-5.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.el6_8.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /etc/sonarqube-5.6/temp/sq-process9097519531831087404properties
jvm 1    | 2016.07.25 10:26:09 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2016.07.25 10:26:09 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.el6_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/etc/sonarqube-5.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.el6_8.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/etc/sonarqube-5.6/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /etc/sonarqube-5.6/temp/sq-process7894674733069325694properties
jvm 1    | 2016.07.25 10:26:18 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2016.07.25 10:26:18 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

---

part of the log:
logs/sonar.log

```
2016.07.25 10:26:03 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2016.07.25 10:26:05 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469413554129] initialized
2016.07.25 10:26:05 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469413554129] starting ...
2016.07.25 10:26:05 WARN   es[o.e.common.network]  failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback
java.net.UnknownHostException: code-manage.novalocal: code-manage.novalocal: unknown error
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
```

Comment: Add an entry for that hostname (`code-manage.novalocal`) to your local hosts file (`/etc/hosts`).

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related sites superuser.com OR unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Indeed DNS configuration is not correct. That deserves to be a SO answer.